# A scale of intensity for synonyms of the word- "lying"

Tags: etymology, synonyms

Can someone arrange for me the words- **"Dissemble, prevarication, lying, equivocation, waffle"** on a scale based on the intensity of the meaning they convey?

(Scale: least to most i.e. euphemism to slang)

Comment: There is no such scale. Language doesn't work like that. And those words are not, of course, perfectly synonymous, so how "intense" they are will depend on context (because context will influence their meaning).

Comment: I've never thought of 'waffle' being synonymous with being untruthful. Sometimes it is just verbosity for its own sake and sometimes it is attempting to disguise a lack of knowledge, it is about being vague; havering. Google suggests that in US English *waffle* means what  swither means to me.

Comment: If you're a politician, is it considered worse to "waffle" or "flip flop"?  BTW, can you clarify the basis for selecting those terms in particular, and excluding related terms like "fibbing", "white lie", "obfuscation", etc,?

Answer (score 2):

This is a loose ordering based on **intent**:

•   Lying (outright deception)

> Disposed to or characterized by untruth. (American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.)

•   Prevarication (exaggerating or evading)

> To speak or write evasively (American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.)

•   Equivocation (fudging logic through distracting truths)

> A statement that is not literally false but that cleverly avoids an unpleasant truth. (Based on WordNet 3.0)

•   Dissembling (hiding behind a mask)

> To disguise or conceal one's real nature, motives, or feelings behind a false appearance. (American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.)

•   Waffling (being indecisive without intent to lie)

> To be unable to make a decision; waver: *He waffled over whether to ask for a raise.* (American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.)

Comment: The original question asked for a "(Scale: least to most i.e. euphemism to slang)" - so it appears you have your scale back to front? Nice answer though, be sure to tag me if you re-order it, so I can + 1 !

Comment: @Gary - I ordered my answer least to most, according to the attempt to mask the intent of avoiding the truth. I can help best when I interpret the questions loosely. How many people look for a pet term that is two words but specify they want one word? I do not hold that against them nor withhold the answer because they limit my response.